# Symfony- Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'timestamp' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine

i get this error when i am trying to set the column type to datetime

```
 /**
 ** @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $timestamp;
```

Error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                                                       
 An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE fos_user CHANGE timestamp 
 timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT NULL':  
 SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' 
for column 'timestamp' at row 1
```

Comment: error message seems pretty descriptive to me

Comment: @bassxzero i get the error when trying to update the schema. the timestamp column is originally "string" but trying to update to timestamp instead. cant figure out what the problem is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set NULL for all records where timestamp = '' and then try you update one more time.

It seems you already have timestamp column and try to migrate it to 'DATETIME DEFAULT NULL'. But because some of records have empty strings ('') which are not NULL or date values it raised an error.

Comment: @Suleiman you are welcome! can you mark this answer as correct? thanks!

Comment: Done 

Comment: it is working but it is not solution, after upgrade from symfony 3.3.16 to 3.4.9 must be some change maded to doctrine datetypes, and probably neded some fix in config.yml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Symfony 5+ and this one worked for me

```
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE _yourTableName ADD date DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL');
```

Then make your migration .